# Group range of dates in SQL query

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery, partition-by

I have a SQL table in which I save a record that contains a `DATE` field, in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format. I'm trying to compute an average over partitions of the table defined by a months range, i.e. I want to group the rows by a window of dates between August and July of the next year, and then compute the average of a field in each partition.

How can I do this automatically, instead of using a
`WHERE day BETWEEN ('1995-08-01' AND '1996-07-31' OR '1996-08-01' AND '1997-07-31')`etc..,
 since the data can grow indefinitely?

Sample data from the table

```
div date                    hometeam        awayteam    fthg    ftag
E0  2017-04-17 00:00:00.000 Middlesbrough   Arsenal     1       2
E0  2017-04-16 00:00:00.000 Man United      Chelsea     2       0
E0  2017-04-16 00:00:00.000 West Brom       Liverpool   0       1
E0  2017-04-15 00:00:00.000 Crystal Palace  Leicester   2       2
E0  2017-04-15 00:00:00.000 Everton         Burnley     3       1
```

I want to group the matches by soccer season instead of the year.

Comment: Can you please provide sample data from your table?

Comment: Added, sorry @SabriKaragönen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shift the date to the new year, and then extract year from that date.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(year from DATE_ADD(CAST(dt AS date), interval 5 month)) as season
```

To understand it better, I prepared a step by step query

```
SELECT dt, 
  DATE_ADD(CAST(dt AS date), interval 5 month) as shifted_dt, 
  EXTRACT(year from DATE_ADD(CAST(dt AS date), interval 5 month)) as season
FROM UNNEST(['1995-08-01', '1996-07-31', '2017-04-16', '1996-08-01', '1997-07-31']) as dt
```

[image]